# How To create Multilevel Spinner in Android

Tags: android

Hi I am Developing an Android application for product distribution. I have my Products self-referencing **(Parent->child)** concept. ex. **Samsung->Mobile->J7 (Product 3 Level)**, or **Samsung->Laptop (Product 2 level).** So I want to display Samsung in First Spinner. If Select Samsung, automatically new spinner should be created,and fill with **Mobile and Laptop List**. If again selects **Mobile**, a new spinner should appear with list **J7**, else if select Laptop, then no need to create new spinner.